# Formatting word (.docx) document using python

Tags: python-3.x, ms-word

I want to read a word document line by line and if it contains a word with red colored font, I want to remove that whole line.
The document also contains Table, so if it is present in table then I want to delete that table.

I am new to python, and I tried using Document Library in python to read the contents in table and in document. But I am unable to get (extract) the font of the word to decide further operation.

for paragraphs:

```
t=0
for i in docx.paragraphs:
    t=0
    if len(i.text.strip())!=0:
        for k in i.runs:
            if(k.font.color.rgb == (0xFF, 0x00, 0x00)):
                t+=1
        if t==0:
            i.clear()
```

and for tables:

```
t=0
for table in docx.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            for i in cell.paragraphs:
                t=0
                if len(i.text.strip())!=0:
                    for k in i.runs:
                        if(k.font.color.rgb == (0xFF, 0x00, 0x00)):
                            t+=1
                            #print(t)
    if(t==0):
        #print('cleared table')
        table._element.getparent().remove(table._element)
```